# How to show specific records from a RAML file in anypoint studio?

Tags: anypoint-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I have used HTTP requester to use external mulesoft training API URL. I want to view only this 3 specific records to end-users after sending GET requests in Postman, like

"destination": "LAX",
 "ID": 10,
 "code": "eefd4511",

I tried using Dataweave transformation but it is not working efficiently.[example responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHHq1.png)

Answer (score 0):

are you aware of query parameters? you might need to verify your RAML file to ensure that the GET endpoint is configured to accept certain query-parameters and you can pass it as per the usage described. one example would be to assume that the mule app is equipped to accept a query parameter called destination to which you can pass a value and it acts as a filter where in you will get results back containing files which are destined to go to the location you passed.

an example of url will be http://localhost:1234/api/flights?destination=LAX

Comment: Thanks for helping but, I do not want to use query parameters for this scenario, I directly want these destinations (SFO, CLE) to be directly shown to the user with ID and Code only.

Comment: oho you mean to say you need the mule code to invoke the above url and then filter the result and show only specific fields and specific records?